# Past perfect, past perfect cont

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, past-tense, past-perfect

Is it correct to say?

> I got burned 2 weeks ago and got scorch on my hand. It hadn't been getting better until 1 week had passed

should I use past perfect at the end or would simple past be more correct?

> I got burned 2 weeks ago and got scorch on my hand. It hadn't been getting better until 1 week passed

Comment: It would be better to say _It didn't start to get better until a week had passed_ (or simply _for a week_).

Answer (score 0):

> I got burned 2 weeks ago and got scorch on my hand. It hadn't been getting better until 1 week had passed

A proposed choice:

"I got burned 2 weeks ago and scorch*ed* my hand. It didn't start to get better for a week."

Why do we use this different wording? There is definitely a logical reason, however to a native speaker, one just sounds "better" than the other. To analyze a bit further: the "start" of a process is not continuous. It is more or less instantaneous. Thus, you would not use the past perfect *continuous* tense (had been) to describe a start.

Regarding scorch versus scorched: a [Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20scorched%2C%20got%20scorch) search for "got scorch" shows 0 results. It's more common to use scorch in the verb form, where scorched is the past participle.

Answer (score 0):

“I got burned 2 weeks ago and got scorch on my hand. It hadn't been getting better until 1 week had passed”

A better way to say this: “I got burned 2 weeks ago and scorched my hand. It didn’t start to get better until a week had passed”

An alternative: “I had burnt my myself 2 weeks ago and scorched my hand. It didn’t start to get better until a week had passed”